# Calculate area under histogram bins

Tags: histograms

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]]
```

How to calculate the area under the histogram.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: manually calculating the area under each rectangle and summing them

Comment: I must be missing something about your question.  Wouldn't the area always be the sample size times the bin width (using the default options for `Histogram` ?  And if you used the "PDF" option for *hspec*, the area would always be exactly 1.

Comment: Area is the sum of (frequency times the bin width).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one sample of the random generated data

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200];
```

and the associated historgram

```
Histogram[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coordinates of the plot can be derived by:

```
histList = HistogramList[data]
(* {{-(5/2), -2, -(3/2), -1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2},
    {6, 7, 25, 42, 43, 28, 33, 11, 5}} *)
```

We set it equal to a variable, `histList` for later use.

Note that the part one of `histList` is of length 11 and part two is length 10.

Part one defines the x-axis coordinates of the rectangle and part two the associated heights.

In order to compute the area one can use either `Map` or `Table` to get the individual rectangles, and then apply `Total` to the list of areas.

```
Total@
 Map[(histList[[1, # + 1]] - histList[[1, #]])*histList[[2, #]] &, 
  Range[Length@histList[[2]]]]

(* 100 *)
```

Comment: Map[(histList[[1, # + 1]] - histList[[1, #]])*histList[[2, #]] &, 
  Range[Length@histList[[2]]]]
i don't understand this part.

Comment: `Map` applies a function (in this case, the area of the rectangle) to the list 1 thru 10. It is equivalent to `Table[(histList[[1, i + 1]] - histList[[1, i]])*histList[[2, i]], {i, 
  1, Length@histList[[2]]}]` which might be easier for you to understand. Check out `Map` and/or `Table` in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to calculate that?

The third argument of `Histogram` controls the meaning of the bin height. The default is `"Count"`.  Thus your result for `Histogram[data]` would simply be `Length[data]`.

Comment: Homework problem. `Length[Data]` gives me the total size i.e 200 in this case whereas `Histogram[Data]` gives histogram of the distribution.